# Unable to access View of Fragment with ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

Trying to learn Android development by poking around so please forgive if the query is too simple.

I have the following code which keeps crashing due to NullPointerException - I hve tried several ways to access the View of the Fragment but I always get null. Can anyone help me out with what I'm doing wrong?

What I'm trying to do is save the contents of the EditText to SharedPreferences when the page is scrolled. For the life of me, I can't seem to access the View of the fragment that is loaded when the tab is displayed.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    // Tab Titles
    private String tabtitles[] = new String[] { "Profile", "Address", 
    "Security"};
    Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            // Open FragmentTab1.java
            case 0:
                CreateUserFragmentProfile fragmenttab1 = new 
                CreateUserFragmentProfile();
                return fragmenttab1;
            // Open FragmentTab2.java
            case 1:
                CreateUserFragmentLocation fragmenttab2 = new 
                CreateUserFragmentLocation();
                return fragmenttab2;
            // Open FragmentTab3.java
            case 2:
                CreateUserFragmentSecurity fragmenttab3 = new 
                CreateUserFragmentSecurity();
                return fragmenttab3;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabtitles[position];
    }

}
```

The Fragment code extends Fragment, and does pretty much nothing.

```
public class CreateUserFragmentSecurity extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
    container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, 
    savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_fragment_security, 
    container, false);


        return view;

    }

    public void  storeData(){

    }
}
```

The Activity code is as follows:

```
public class CreateUser extends AppCompatActivity {


    public SharedPreferences preferences;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public View currView;
    public String fname, lname, dob, gender, email, addr1, addr2, addr3, 
    addrstate, city, passwd, passwdPlain;
    public Long mobile, pin;
    //public FragmentPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("Reviv", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();

        // Locate the viewpager in activity_create_user.xml
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager

        final FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new 
        ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new 
            ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, 
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
                boolean hasChanged = false;
                switch (position){ // store data on tab switch
                    case 0: // Profile tab
                        //currView = 
               viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem());  // returns 
               null
                        currView = 
               adapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getView();  // 
               crashes, returns null
                        EditText etFname = 
               currView.findViewById(R.id.etFname);


                        fname = etFname.getText().toString();

                        hasChanged = false;

                        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(fname)) {
                            editor.putString("fname", fname);
                            hasChanged = true;
                        }

                        if(hasChanged == true) editor.commit();

                        break;
                    case 1: // Address tab
                        // currView = 
             viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem()); // returns 
             null
                        currView = 
             adapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getView();
                        EditText etAddr1 = 
             currView.findViewById(R.id.etAddr1);



                        addr1 = etAddr1.getText().toString();


                        hasChanged = false;

                        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(addr1)) {
                            editor.putString("addr1", addr1);
                            hasChanged = true;
                        }


                        if(hasChanged == true) editor.commit();


                        break;
                    case 2: // Security tab
                        //currView = 
          viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem()); // returns null
                        currView = 
          adapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getView();

                        EditText etPasswd = 
          currView.findViewById(R.id.etPasswd);


                        passwd = etPasswd.getText().toString();

                        hasChanged = false;

                        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(passwd)) {
                            editor.putString("passwd", passwd);
                            hasChanged = true;
                        }



                        if(hasChanged == true) editor.commit();

                        break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
               // do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // do nothing
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Stack trace is as follows:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   com.portmanteau.reviv.CreateUser$1.onPageScrolled(CreateUser.java:58)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1921)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onPageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1895)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.pageScrolled(ViewPager.java:1833)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:690)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1777)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19678)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6057)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19678)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6057)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19678)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6057)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:434)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19678)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6057)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19678)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6057)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19678)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6057)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19678)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6057)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2510)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2219)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1405)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6829)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:713)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6803)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: If you are just saving the data in `SharedPreferences` you can do that directly in the fragment itself.

Comment: I could but the event that triggers the save is an onPageScrolled - basically, saves the contents of the tab to SharedPreferences when the user scrolls to the next tab.

Comment: Also tried your suggestion by using onPause and onResume but as there are only 3 tabs, they are never called. Any other suggestion for me to try?

Comment: can you post your layout xml

Comment: Sure : Activity : https://pastebin.com/4TwMSK1K
Fragment 1  : https://pastebin.com/qPFsdMZD
Fragment 2 : https://pastebin.com/w8asVrTG
Fragment 3 : https://pastebin.com/He1UTrcP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    boolean hasChanged = false;
    if (positionOffset > 0) {
        currView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + position).getView();
        if (currView != null) {
            EditText editText = null;
            if (position == 0) editText = currView.findViewById(R.id.etPasswdPlain);
            else if (position == 1) editText = currView.findViewById(R.id.etAddr1);
            else if (position ==2) editText = currView.findViewById(R.id.etFname);
            if (editText != null) {
                String value = editText.getText().toString();
                Log.d("TAG", "Value is " + value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will work only if you are **doing left to right swipe** ( from page 1 to page 2 and page 2 to page 3).

i.e when you are swiping from **page 1** to **page 2**, data in **page 1** is saved and

when you are swiping from **page 2** to **page 3**, data in **page 2** will be saved.

For `right to left swipe` assuming that you have to save **page 3** data when swiping from **page 3 to page 2** and save **page 2** data when swiping from **page 2 to page 1**, you have to do some logic but you can get the idea from here.

Comment: Thanks so much. This code worked and i also think I understand how it does what it does . Also, i'm poking around with the offset and got a rough feel of how the RTL swipe can be captured.  +1 for the lucid explanation. :)

Comment: Hi, I've been able to successfully save all the editTexts from the first 2 fragments to SharedPreferences but the third fragment's Logd is never called no matter which side the swipe is (RTL, LTR). How do I access those when I do an onPageScrolled ?

My code is here : https://pastebin.com/BXfXt9Rs

Comment: @kilokahn Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667459/how-to-know-viewpager-is-scroll-left-or-right#26677301) for detecting swipe direction.

Comment: Got it and managed to fix my code to detect swipe direction. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
((EditText) viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem())
    .findViewById(R.id.etFname)).getText().toString()
```

rather than

```
adapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getView();
```

Comment: I tried it and I still get an NullPointerException :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: Could you suggest any other alternatives? Is there any particular reason I'm getting the NPE?

Comment: I tried the solution I proposed, it worked fine for me. Can you check if viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem()) is null or not?

Comment: No luck - I keep getting the NPE and crash. Sharing the entire code with you - can you please take a look?

Activity - https://pastebin.com/utaBPhac

Comment: I saw the code you shared, looks fine to me. Just need to know if viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem()) is null or your Edittext is null.

Comment: So I've been poking around and for some reason the viewPager.getCurrentItem() returns null. The editText is blank by default.

Comment: viewPager.getCurrentItem() can't be null, it returns an int value, whose default value is 0. It should never be null. Try logging its value.