# how to determine if I do scroll in ViewPager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

See next [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13667527/6387618) in so, but here simply I can determine that has changed page. How can i determine when a user is scrolling `ViewPager`?

Comment: The answer below the one you posted shows you how - `onPageScrollStateChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an `OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager` and override its methods. When the pager is scrolled, the method `onPageScrolled` is called while it's scrolled, so you can use that.

```
view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : OnPageChangeListener {
            ...

            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int) 
            {
                Log.d("Debugging", "Pager is now scrolling: $positionOffset")
            }

            ...

        })
```

You can also use the method `onPageScrollStateChanged` from `OnPageChangeListener` to find out when the scrolling state is changing. The `state` param of that method can be `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`, `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`, `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING`.